# Find the rectangle of the currently selected item in a list box

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I need the find the rectangle (or really just top, left point) of the selected item in a List Box.

Any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[P/Invoke SendMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SendMessage) with [LB_GETITEMRECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453262.aspx).